# POST to ServiceStack Service and retrieve Location Header

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to POST to my ServiceStack service and retrieve the Location header from the response of my CREATED entity. I am not sure whether using IReturn is valid but I am not sure how to access the Response headers from my client. 
Can someone help me understand how to interact with the HttpResult properly? There is a test case at the bottom of the code to demonstrate what I want to do.
Here's the codz:

```
    public class ServiceStackSpike
{
    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("TODOs Tests", typeof(Todo).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            //noop
        }
    }


    [Route("/todos", "POST")]
    public class Todo:IReturn<HttpResult>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }
    }


    public class TodosService : Service
    {
        public object Post(Todo todo)
        {
            //do stuff here
            var result = new HttpResult(todo,HttpStatusCode.Created);
            result.Headers[HttpHeaders.Location] = "/tada";
            return result;
        }


    }


    public class NewApiTodosTests : IDisposable
    {
        const string BaseUri = "http://localhost:82/";

        AppHost appHost;

        public NewApiTodosTests()
        {
            appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start(BaseUri);                
        }


        [Fact]
        public void Run()
        {
            var restClient = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);


            var todo = restClient.Post(new Todo { Content = "New TODO", Order = 1 });
            Assert.Equal(todo.Headers[HttpHeaders.Location], "/tada"); //=>fail
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            appHost.Dispose();
            appHost = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [Customizing HTTP Responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Customize-HTTP-Responses) ServiceStack wiki page for all the different ways of customizing the HTTP Response.

A `HttpResult` is just one way customize the HTTP Response. You generally want to include the Absolute Url if you're going to redirect it, e.g:

```
public object Post(Todo todo)
{
    var todo = ...;
    return new HttpResult(todo, HttpStatusCode.Created) { 
        Location = base.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith("/tada")
    };
}
```

Note HTTP Clients will **never** see a `HttpResult` DTO. HttpResult is **not a DTO** itself, it's only purpose is to capture and modify the customized HTTP Response you want.

All ServiceStack Clients will return is the HTTP Body, which in this case is the `Todo` Response DTO. The **Location** is indeed added to the HTTP Response headers, and to see the entire HTTP Response returned you should use a HTTP sniffer like Fiddler, WireShark or Chrome's WebInspector.

If you want to access it using ServiceStack's HTTP Clients, you will need to add a Response Filter that gives you access to the `HttpWebResponse`, e.g:

```
restClient.ResponseFilter = httpRes => {
      Assert.Equal(httpRes.Headers[HttpHeaders.Location], "/tada"); 
 };

Todo todo = restClient.Post(new Todo { Content = "New TODO", Order = 1 });
```

#### Inspecting Response Headers using Web Request Extensions

Another lightweight alternative if you just want to inspect the HTTP Response is to use ServiceStack's Convenient WebRequest extension methods, e.g:

```
var url = "http://path/to/service";
var json = url.GetJsonFromUrl(httpRes => {
      Assert.Equal(httpRes.Headers[HttpHeaders.Location], "/tada"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Demis! That answers my question. It seems like having filters applied globally will force me into conditional handling of responses now, though :( . The POSTs to the service I am actually talking to don't return an entity Body, only the Location header to where I can find the newly created resource. Is there a better approach to make the request and simply inspect the headers upon response?

Comment: It looks the best approach is to simply treat client instances as transient. In this case, per-request client. It still unnaturally splits the request-response logic but is better than filters containing conditional checks.

Comment: I've updated it to show an alternative lighter-weight way of accessing the response headers.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks for the answer and for the framework. It has been a pleasure to work with.

Comment: This should referenced from the documentation, great answer. Thank you