# Performing redirects in ServiceStack

Tags: http, http-headers, servicestack

I'm attempting to build a service in ServiceStack whose sole responsibility will be to interpret requests, and send a redirect response. Something like this:

```csharp
[Route("/redirect/", "POST")    
public class Redirect : IReturnVoid
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

public class RedirectService : Service
{
    public object Post(Redirect req)
    {
        // make some decisions about stuff

        return new HttpResult(){ StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect, Headers = {{HttpHeaders.Location, "place"}}};
    }
}
```

I did initial testing using fiddler, setting a content-type of application/json and creating an appropriate request body.This did exactly as expected: the service request gave a 302 response and redirected to the expected location.

I've also tested this by using a basic Html form post, with an action of `http://myserviceuri/redirect/`, which also works as expected and redirects appropriately.

However, i've hit an issue when attempting to use the SS c# client to call the same service. If I call the following code in an aspx code behind or an mvc controller

```js
var client = new JsonServiceClient("uri);

client.post(new Redirect{Something = "something});
```

I get a 500 and the error message:

`The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

Which makes sense as it's a development server, with a self-cert. But I get the feeling that, as I can call the service successfully by other means, that this is a red herring.

Should I be using a different type of c# client to make the request, or setting any more custom headers, or something else? Am I fundamentally not understanding what i'm trying to do?

Please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the `JsonServiceClient` is happily following the redirect, doing more than what you've expected it to do.

I'll reference a related question and answer for posterity ( - hopefully you've resolved this issue a long time ago...).

[POST to ServiceStack Service and retrieve Location Header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13462496/620856)

Essentially you'd use .net's `WebRequest` or the ServiceStack extensions mentioned in the answer to see the redirect and act as you see fit.