# How do I access the HTTP headers in the ServiceStack v4 ServiceClient?

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack v3 I could check the `HttpStatusCode` or `Location` headers with the `LocalHttpWebResponseFilter`:

```cs
var client = new JsvServiceClient(ServiceUrl);
client.LocalHttpWebResponseFilter = delegate(HttpWebResponse httpRes)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(httpRes.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Created);
};
```

Related post: [POST to ServiceStack Service and retrieve Location Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460993/post-to-servicestack-service-and-retrieve-location-header)

The filter is missing in ServiceStack v4. I couldn't find any alternatives. Is checking the HTTP headers still supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added the following to the [v4.0 Release Notes Changes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#wiki-whats-new-in-v4):

- The **LocalHttpWebRequestFilter** and **LocalHttpWebResponseFilter** in the Service Clients were renamed to just `RequestFilter` and `ResponseFilter`
- The Global **HttpWebRequestFilter** and **HttpWebResponseFilter** filters were also renamed to `GlobalRequestFilter` and `GlobalResponseFilter` respectively.

Comment: That was kinda stupid of me. My factory actually returned an IServiceClient and I obviously searched on the interface :/. Thanks for the quick response mythz.